# Tipo password en android EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Al introducir la contraseña quiero que salgan *, puntos o algo para que no se vea. Tengo el siguiente editText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

¿Alguien sabe de alguna propiedad o algo para esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes realizar lo que deseas especificando el atributo [android:inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType) y la constante `textPassword` en tu `EditText`:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

al escribir se mostrará el caracter "*" :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes revisar la documentación para más información sobre

**[Especificar el tipo de método de entrada en un EditText](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)**

Comment: perfecto, gracias Jorge.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, saludos.